Exception in thread main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/messagingException
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingExceprion while sending mail
Activation.jar, javax.mail.jar also in classpath.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException
at com.isg.webportal.module.iDashboard.model.SendHLScrnMail.main(SendHLScrnMail.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.MessagingException
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
... 1 more
